# viewport is not a function error in .js

Tags: javascript, function

I'm totally new in javascript, I have the following error "Uncaught TypeError: viewport is not a function   scripts.min.js:279" and I do not understand how to fix it. Any idea what is wrong?
Thanks.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
    function smartSidebars() {   //<==== line 279
     var width = viewport().width;
     var st = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
     //see which direction we're going 
     if (st > lastScrollTop){
      var direction = 'down';
     } else {
      var direction = 'up';
     }
     affixObject(jQuery('.post-left'), jQuery('.post-right'), direction, false); 
     if(width > 991) {
      affixObject(jQuery('.loop-sidebar-left'), jQuery('.main-post-container'), direction, true);
      affixObject(jQuery('.loop-sidebar-right'), jQuery('.main-post-container'), direction, true);
      affixObject(jQuery('.single-sidebar'), jQuery('.post-right'), direction, true);
     } else {
      moveLoop();
     }
     lastScrollTop = st;  
    }


//-----------------------------------------------------------


function viewport() {
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window )) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] };
}
```

Comment: Looks like `viewport()` is not defined in the correct scope. Is it supposed to be a global?

Comment: I agree with Kevin. Is it in the same file? Are they loaded correctly?

Comment: Yes is it in same file. Here is entire file https://pastebin.com/v6ZS2KVy

Comment: Is it possible you're referencing the wrong file? The error points to scripts.min.js, but the pastebin link isn't minimized, so did you paste from another .js file thinking that's the one it's looking in?

Comment: Oh sorry for that, here is minimized one https://pastebin.com/ipWXnUm7 , anyway any of them I use will be getting the same error